# How to select list item in HTML with Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have objects returned from $http call, as JSON. HTML where are items:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a data-target="#ModalNPPInfo0" data-toggle="modal" class="col-xs-9 mt13" href="#">                 
        <p class="meta-list-text"> {{ object.name }} </p>
     </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

HTML where I need to show object data:

```
 <dl class="dl-horizontal left-align mt10 mb15">
                                <dt>Name</dt>
                                <dd>{{ object.name }}</dd>
                                <dt>Sequence</dt>
                                <dd>{{ object.sequenceNumber }}</dd>
                                <dt>Start</dt>
                                <dd>{{ object.beginDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy.' }}</dd>

 </dl>
```

So, when clicked on item in list, it should open window (#ModalNPPInfo0) with object.name which is selected on list. How to tell Angular I selected (clicked) on exactly that object.name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngClick directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick):

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="openModal(object)">
<a data-target="#ModalNPPInfo0" data-toggle="modal" class="col-xs-9 mt13">                 
        <p class="meta-list-text"> {{ object.name }} </p>
     </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalNPPInfo0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal left-align mt10 mb15"> <dt>Name</dt>

                            <dd>{{ selectedObject.name }}</dd> <dt>Sequence</dt>

                            <dd>{{ selectedObject.sequenceNumber }}</dd> <dt>Start</dt>

                            <dd>{{ selectedObject.beginDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy.' }}</dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then create `openModal` function in controller that will open your modal.

**javascript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.object = {
        name: "John",
        sequenceNumber: "123",
        beginDate: "12/12/2014"
    }

    $scope.selectedObject = {};

    $scope.openModal = function (object) {
        $scope.selectedObject = object;
    }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/LkxGG/2/)**

Comment: Are you sure I need to put ng-click here where I need to show the data and not up wher is the item that I'm clicking on in <p>?

Comment: @firstChild, I thougt you are clicking on `dl` item. So yes, if you clicking on `<p>` then place `ng-click` there.